# building example of canopen from canfestival error

Tags: c++, windows, can-bus, canopen

I've got canopen source from canfestival.
I got errors when I built its win32test example on visual stdio, 
there wasn't any lib file in file that I downloaded and extracted.
any help would be appreciated. 
the errors:
error C2065: 'win32test_obj100C': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'win32test_obj100D': undeclared identifier

Comment: My crystal ball told me you configured that library wrong before building :-P ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem in built object dictionary

I make another object dictionary header and source with its .od file in cygwin and the errors gone